# Open HTML file in popup window by default

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have an html page (quiz.html) which I want to have a shortcut for on desktop. I want, when users click on the shortcut icon the file opens in popup window with no adress bar, toolbar etc (default by browser).

The code for that is `window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","width=200,height=100",'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');`

But it works only on buttons. How can I set it up to open from desktop like I want?

Comment: what you mean? so when the person save the short code and later open the site from still be a pop up?

Comment: No. I want to have an icon on local computer (quiz.html). So when person double clicks on it, it opens directly in a pop-up window of browser without any of these toolbars, addressbars, buttons etc...

Comment: look into chrome packaged apps, firefox apps, HTA apps, node-webkit, adobe AIR, and Chrome's "Create Application Shortcuts". you can't do just a pop-up without leaving the launching page behind in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these:

[Javascript's `window.resizeTo` isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602078/javascripts-window-resizeto-isnt-working)

[Self resize and center a window using javascript (no jquery) on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866418/self-resize-and-center-a-window-using-javascript-no-jquery-on-page-load)

[Javascript set browser window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238603/javascript-set-browser-window-size)

and get some ideas or conclusions